# If I want to create Web Parts using SPFx, do I need to be an O365 Admin User?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, spfx

I'm working on learning to use SPFx, and I'm following Microsoft's guide ([Up to Part 3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page)). Will I need to be elevated to an O365 Admin for my company in order to continue? Or will I be able to gain access to the App Catalog without needing this elevated permission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your administrator can give you permission to upload packages to the App Catalog. The permissions work the same way they do in any "normal" site collection.

[image: App Catalog]